# Error in ActionCable with Apartment gem and Stimulus Reflex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, actioncable, apartment-gem, stimulusjs

I'm developing a multi tenant app, in Rails 6 with ActionCable, the gem Apartment and Stimulus Reflex.

`connection.rb`

`
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

```
def connect
  tenant = request.subdomain
  Apartment::Tenant.switch!(tenant)
  self.current_user = find_verified_user
  logger.add_tags "ActionCable", "User #{current_user.id}", "Tenant #{tenant}"
end

protected

  def find_verified_user
    if current_user = env['warden'].user
      current_user
    else
      reject_unauthorized_connection
    end
  end
```

end
end`

I have this, until now:

`development.rb`

`config.hosts << ".lvh.me"
config.action_cable.url = 'ws://lvh.me:3000/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http:\/\/*.lvh.me:3000*']`

By implementing this line of code in connection.rb: `logger.add_tags "ActionCable", "User #{current_user.id}", "Tenant #{tenant}"` i can see in the console that everything it's ok at beginning, but as soon i call any Stimulus Reflex action it shows this: `The ActionCable connection is not open! this.isActionCableConnectionOpen() must return true before calling this.stimulate()`. I'm developing the app in a Vagrant box since i'm in a Windows machine, perhaps the problem is in there, but i'm not sure. Please help, i have no clue about how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Got any solution to this problem yet?